# Python, loop for non-array elemnts

Tags: python, json

I am receiving the following Json block from client. Though the Items is not an array but I need to process it as array in Python. Is there any proper way ?

{
  "Order": "1234",
  "Date":"2020-02-10",
  "Items":{
     "0": {"ItemID": "I1",
           "Qty": "4",
           "Value":"3.40"
           },
     "1": {"ItemID": "W4",
           "Qty": "2",
           "Value":"1.40"
           },
     "15": {"ItemID": "D2",
           "Qty": "1",
           "Value":"4.00"
   }
}

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You know you can convert jsons to dictionaries in Python with the json package? Then you just have to loop through the Items-dictionary...

Comment: Can you share a minimal version of the code you want to run?

Comment: if you can use `pandas` , it has a [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(your_dict['Items']).T`

Comment: What would the array for this look like?

Comment: Take a look at [the json module in the Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), which is perfect for encoding Python objects into JSON and decoding JSON into Python objects.

Comment: Thanks All. I managed to process it with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate them, or create an array during the iteration if is needed:

```
import json

data_str = '{ "Order": "1234", "Date":"2020-02-10", "Items":{ "0": {"ItemID": "I1", "Qty": "4", "Value":"3.40" }, "1": {"ItemID": "W4", "Qty": "2", "Value":"1.40" }, "15": {"ItemID": "D2", "Qty": "1", "Value":"4.00" } } }'

data = json.loads(data_str)
for item_index in data["Items"]
    print(item_index + ' :: ' + str(data["Items"][item_index]))
```

And the result:

```
1 :: {u'ItemID': u'W4', u'Value': u'1.40', u'Qty': u'2'}
0 :: {u'ItemID': u'I1', u'Value': u'3.40', u'Qty': u'4'}
15 :: {u'ItemID': u'D2', u'Value': u'4.00', u'Qty': u'1'}
```

Comment: Thanks, it gave me a direction